# Flutter IntlPhoneField run function on valid phone number (intl_phone_field)

Tags: flutter

I'm using the `intl_phone_field` package to verify phone numbers based on country code.

The `IntlPhoneField` checks automatically for invalid phone numbers, and prompt a message respectively.

It support `onChange`, `onSubmit` and `onSaved` functions, but does not support an `onValid` function.

**I want to enable/disable a Submit Button, based on package's validate function, Since it already supports many country codes and different phone number lengths.**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntlPhoneField(
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Phone Number',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        counterText: '',
      ),
      initialCountryCode: 'US',
      // countries: const ['US'],
    );
  }
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I have opened a pull request with a solution in the GitHub project https://github.com/vanshg395/intl_phone_field/pull/217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved!

I detected validation using the `intl_phone_field` package by exporting the `Country` object, which contains the `minLength` and `maxLength` of the country code phone number.

Using those parameters I verified the phone number in the `onChange` function and a function in case of verified phone number.

```
class PhonePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhonePicker({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const _initialCountryCode = 'US';
    var _country =
        countries.firstWhere((element) => element.code == _initialCountryCode);

    return IntlPhoneField(
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Phone Number',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        counterText: '',
      ),
      initialCountryCode: _initialCountryCode,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.number.length >= _country.minLength &&
            value.number.length <= _country.maxLength) {
          // Run anything here
        }
      },
      onCountryChanged: (country) => _country = country,
    );
  }
}
```

I have opened a pull request with a solution in the GitHub [project](https://github.com/vanshg395/intl_phone_field/pull/217#issue-1345594129).

Answer (score 0):

You can a state variable and  use `validator` data to check whether number is valid or not

```dart
 bool isValid = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        IntlPhoneField(
          autofocus: true,
          validator: (p0) {
            /// logic to validate number
            /// isValid =true
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Phone Number',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            counterText: '',
          ),
          initialCountryCode: 'US',
          // countries: const ['US'],
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: isValid ? () {} : null, child: child)
      ],
    );
```

Also you can use `TextEditingController` with listener and check data and enable button state. make sure to use setState.

Comment: Hey @Yeasin, I want to use the built-in package validate function since it already supports different phone number lengths based on country codes. How do I trigger UI changes using the build-in validation?

Comment: then it will be tricky, if you know certain length is valid one, use textEditingController

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Boolean variable and then use validator inside `IntlPhoneField`:

```
bool isPhoneValidated = false;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntlPhoneField(
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Phone Number',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        counterText: '',
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isValidNumber()) {
           setState(() {
              isPhoneValidated = true;
           });
        } else {
           setState(() {
              isPhoneValidated = false;
           });
        }
        return null;
      },
      initialCountryCode: 'US',
      // countries: const ['US'],
    );
  }
```

Now, before navigating, just check if the Boolean variable is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

in the official document of the package you will find that you can validate it using :

GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey();

```
  Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: IntlPhoneField( .... rest of your widget
```

and check in your button using the
_formKey.currentState!.validate()